# Input date se muestra vacío con UpdateView en Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Estoy trabajando en Django con UpdateView y ModelForm, al momento de ir a la vista que muestra el formulario para editar el registro, todos mis campos del formulario se llenan con cada valor correspondiente del registro a excepción de uno, y ese es mi campo fecha, se muestra en blanco, totalmente vacío. ¿Debo hacer algo en especial para llenarlo con la fecha que corresponde?

Aquí les dejaré parte de mi código:

#### View

```
class ClienteActualizar(UpdateView):
model = Cliente
form_class = ClienteForm
template_name = 'clientes/crear.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('clientes:principal')
```

#### Form

```
class DateInput(DateInput):
input_type = 'date'


class ClienteForm(ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = Cliente
    fields = (
        'identidad',
        'nombres',
        'apellidos',
        'fecha_nacimiento',
        'direccion',
        'telefono',
        'correo',
        'sexo',
    )
    labels = {
        'identidad': 'Identidad',
        'nombres': 'Nombres',
        'apellidos': 'Apellidos',
        'fecha_nacimiento': 'Fecha de nacimiento',
        'direccion': 'Dirección',
        'sexo': 'Sexo',
        'telefono': 'Teléfono',
        'correo': 'Correo electrónico'
    }
    widgets = {
        'identidad': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'nombres': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'apellidos': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'fecha_nacimiento': DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'direccion': Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows':'5'}),
        'sexo': RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input'}),
        'telefono': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'correo': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    }
```

#### Modelo

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
 identidad = models.CharField(max_length=20)
 nombres = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
 direccion = models.CharField(max_length=300)
 sexo = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, ("Masculino")),
                                    (2, ("Femenino"))),
                           default=1)
 telefono = models.CharField(max_length=9)
 correo = models.EmailField()
```

#### View crear

```
class ClienteCrear(CreateView):
 model = Cliente
 form_class = ClienteForm
 template_name = 'clientes/crear.html'
 success_url = reverse_lazy('clientes:principal')
```

Y bien, no sé si es necesario que agregue algún otro fragmento de código, de ser necesario me avisan, gracias por anticipado.

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba en la base de datos si se está guardando ese dato porque quizás no lo esté mostrando porque no lo está almacenando, puedes hacerle un `print(request.POST)` en la view donde creas ese objeto y comprobar los datos que le pasas. Mira también si en tu modelo tienes este campo como "no obligatorio".

Si sigues con problemas completa la pregunta con tu modelo y la view de crear e intentaré ayudarte.

Contestando a tu pregunta sobre los formatos, puedes probar a añadir algo como esto:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y')

class ClientDetailsForm(ModelForm):
     date_of_birth = DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    class Meta:
         model = ClientDetails
```

Comment: Hola @fdelgado sí se está guardando el dato en la base de datos, una vez que creó el cliente y voy al listado de clientes me aparece la fecha de nacimiento que registré, ahora mismo agrego el modelo y la view de crear... Estoy al pendiente, saludos

Comment: ¿Para editar estas usando un UpdateView?

Comment: Así es @Marcelo estoy usando un UpdateView

Comment: Posiblemente tengas el problema en el template, puedes también intentar imprimir el objeto pintando {{object.fecha_nacimiento}} en tu template para ver si lo está mostrando. Posiblemente el problema venga de la clase DateInput.

Comment: Hola @FDelgado acabo de probar a imprimir el valor, y en efecto, el valor lo recibo y pude imprimirlo en mi template. Inspeccioné el input date donde debe cargar la fecha y veo que en el atributo value tiene el siguiente valor: 23/04/1995 y creo que el valor fecha debería recibirlo así: 1995/04/23 o me equivoco? En caso que sea ese el problema, ¿sabes de qué manera formatear la fecha para que el input date la reciba de esta manera?

Comment: si te está dando un error de formato prueba a añadir una variable en tu formulario que es `{{formulario.errors}}` esto te dará los errores del fórmulario.

Answer (score 0):

En tu forms.py puedes poner

```
self.fields['fecha_nacimiento'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control datetimepicker'})
```

Saludos

Ejemplo:

```
class TuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = tuModel
        fields = ['fecha_nacimiento']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Baplied_95b_uploadform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['fecha_nacimiento'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control datetimepicker'})
```

Comment: Hola @JeanpierreRivas en qué parte del forms.py coloco esa línea de código?

Comment: @EfrainRivera Hola. Edite la respuesta- Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Espero te sirva, así me funciono a mí:

```
fecha_nacimiento = forms.DateField(label='Fecha de nacimiento', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date','class': 'form-control  datetimepicker'}), required=True)
```

Comment: Procura agregar más detalles en tu respuesta: si bien pudo haber sido útil al OP, necesitas detallar tu respuesta para que otros usuarios en un futuro puedan comprender _por qué_ funciona esto. Lee [answer]. Además, dale formato a tu código con el botón que indica `{}`.